# How to create a tag with the same text value?

Tags: jquery-select2

I am using Select2's multi select functionality with the `tags` option to let users enter new values. I need the ability to let a user enter a "tag" with the same text as an existing option. Currently, when a user attempts that, they can only select the existing option.

There is ways to extend Select2 behavior by using [Adapters](https://select2.org/advanced/adapters-and-decorators) but I don't know which part would need to be extended, or if it is possible with Adapters at all, considering that the tagging functionality is implemented using Decorators that, as far as I know, can't be overridden as easily as the Adapters.

I have read some of the Adapter and tagging decorator source to find the code that needs to be changed. I assume the ResultsAdapter might be helpful because I want the result for the new tag to show up even if an option with the same text exists.
So I assumed there would be code somewhere that does something like this pseudo code

```
if (term in options) {
    return false
}
```

Does anyone know what part of the Adapters (or decorators?) I need to change?